# Will I be able to reinstall my copy of Windows 8.1 acquired through DreamSpark on another drive?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, ssd, dreamspark

I've acquired and installed a copy of Windows 8.1 through DreamSpark on my HDD, but I'm planning on getting and SSD in the near future, will I be able to use the same Windows 8.1 copy to install on the new SSD or is the key only allowed for one installation?

Comment: Of course you will.  At the very most you will have to use phone activation to reactivate your copy if that single hardware change is enough to warrant it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reinstalling Windows 8 from Dreamspark](http://superuser.com/questions/492431/reinstalling-windows-8-from-dreamspark)